# Fourier Transforrm of a Wilson Line

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, wilson-loop

Lots of times it is helpful to perform computations of Feynman Diagrams in momentum space as opposed to position space. This however appears a little tricky when it comes to Wilson Lines.

Ignoring issues with Wilson Lines being non-perturbative entities, they are defined as follows

$$
W(x_1,x_2) = \text{Tr}\big[\text{P}\exp\big\{-ig\int_{x_1}^{x_2}dx\cdot A(x)\big\}\big]
$$

I would think that in momentum space, one just has

$$
\hat{W}(p,q) = \int\frac{d^4x_1}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{d^4x_2}{(2\pi)^4}
e^{ip\cdot x_1}e^{iq\cdot x_2}
\text{Tr}\big[\text{P}\exp\big\{-ig\int_{x_1}^{x_2}dx\cdot A(x)\big\}\big]
$$

However in terms of physical intuition, what I wrote was just nonsense. Am I projecting out certain nodes  across all possible Wilson Lines? What about the fact that $W(x_1, x_2) = W(x_2,x_1)^{\dagger}$? How does this factor into the integration.

Is what I wrote nonsense? It is alright if there is no useful application of this quantity. I am just wondering what this even *means*.